# Bootstrap alert on top of navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have added the following code in our layout file on top of the navbar but there is some spacing between the alert and the navbar. I tried to add some CSS, margin bottom: 0 but that margin then applied to all of the alerts on the whole site.

```html
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
 <strong>Moving Servers</strong> You will experience some downtime as we move all of our files onto a new server. This move should be finished on 12/16.
 </div>
   
  
  <!-- Navbar Starts -->
  <header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
```

We just want the alert to be right ontop of the navbar.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your navbar code? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe you will give to this specific alert message his own ID and the try to position it. You probably have done it using his class name.

Comment: I want to post an alert right ontop of the navbar, I will add the whole code. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to use CSS to add a margin to the alert-danger, but that then applied to all of my other alerts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to place it above the `navbar`, make a class to add to it and then use `margin-bottom: 0` so it doesn't change the default alerts.

See working Snippet.

```css
.alert.alert-server {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-server" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
  <strong>Moving Servers</strong> You will experience some downtime as we move all of our files onto a new server. This move should be finished on 12/16.
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You never really provided any CSS examples so I'm not entirely sure how you're trying to implement this, however I do see you're using the `navbar-static-top` class to fix its position and you said you wanted the alert on top of the navbar, so I'll go with that.

You'll need to assign your alert a unique id or class so you can position it on top of the navbar without affecting the other alerts on your page. For example I applied the following styles which fixes the position and gives it a z-index so the navbar doesn't appear on top of the alert:

```
#top-alert {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

And then I assigned the `#top-alert` id to the alert, like so:

```
<div id="top-alert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <strong>Moving Servers</strong> You will experience some downtime as we move all of our files onto a new server. This move should be finished on 12/16.
</div>
```

Altogether this will result in the alert appearing over the top of the navbar.

[image]

Here is a fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/of91yuhu/

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this for some time, in the end this simple solution put an end to my headache...

```
<div class="container-fluid fixed-top p-0">
    <div id="alerts">
        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible m-0 py-1">
            <strong>Alert title</strong> Alert description
            <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-sm p-2" data-bs-        
                dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            Your menu content...
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```